# When to use offsetHeight, clientHeight and scrollHeight and how to find we reached bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, scroll

What's the difference between `offsetHeight`, `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` ?

Also, how to find that we reached bottom of the page considering that page is **dynamically loaded(lazy loading)** as we scroll down ?

Answer (score 1):

[offsetHeight:](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxqbfx.php)

Returns height of an element in px unit. Includes height of `padding`, `scrollBar` and `border` but **NOT** `margin`

---

[clientHeight:](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcadejj.php)

Returns height of an element in px unit. Includes `padding` but **NOT** `scrollBar`, `border` and `margin`

---

[scrollHeight:](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbixkkn.php)

Returns height of an element in px unit. Includes `padding`, `scrollBar`, `border` and `margin`.

---

Same holds for Width in `clientWidth`, `offsetWidth` and `scrollWidth`

**Here is an fiddle:**

```js
function whatis(propType)
{
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("MainDIV");
if(window.sampleDiv==null){
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 window.sampleDiv = div;
}
div = window.sampleDiv;
var propTypeWidth = propType.toLowerCase()+"Width";
var propTypeHeight = propType+"Height";

var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(mainDiv, null);
var borderLeftWidth = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("border-left-width");
var borderTopWidth = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("border-top-width");

div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = mainDiv.offsetLeft+Math.round(parseFloat((propType=="client")?borderLeftWidth:0))+"px";
div.style.top = mainDiv.offsetTop+Math.round(parseFloat((propType=="client")?borderTopWidth:0))+"px";
div.style.height = mainDiv[propTypeHeight]+"px";
div.style.lineHeight = mainDiv[propTypeHeight]+"px";
div.style.width = mainDiv[propTypeWidth]+"px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.innerHTML = propTypeWidth + " X " + propTypeHeight + "( " +
    mainDiv[propTypeWidth] + " x "+ mainDiv[propTypeHeight] + " )";



div.style.background = "rgba(0,0,246,0.5)";
document.body.appendChild(div);

}
document.getElementById("offset").onclick = function(){whatis('offset');}
document.getElementById("client").onclick = function(){whatis('client');}
document.getElementById("scroll").onclick = function(){whatis('scroll');}
```

```css
#MainDIV{
    border:5px solid red;
   }
```

```html
<button id="offset">offsetHeight & offsetWidth</button>
<button id="client">clientHeight & clientWidth</button>
<button id="scroll">scrollHeight & scrollWidth</button>

<div id="MainDIV" style="margin:auto; height:200px; width:400px; overflow:auto;">
<div style="height:400px; width:500px; overflow:hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle copied from: http://jsfiddle.net/shibualexis/yVhgM/3/

Using above mentioned functions to know that we reached bottom of page can be done like this:

```
if((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.scrollHeight )){
   //We reached bottom of page and there is no more vertical scroll can happen.
}
```

Hence, this is how you can make vertical scroll:

```
while(!(window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.scrollHeight )){
     window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Here the condition `(window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.scrollHeight )`  is browser independent and can be run on Chrome, FF, IE and Safari.

Comment: This doesn't answer your own question. Where is the explanation of when and how to use the three? Where is the code and explanation of how to know when you reached the bottom of the page? There's also no Selenium-related code as you tagged your question.

Comment: Please give me sometime. I will edit and keep adding more info.. just reached home.. May be tomorrow morning..